# How do I perform an operation on all elements returned by a query in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I want to do the following:

```
SELECT value FROM ex_tbl WHERE (query);
```

and use every value to do:

```
INSERT INTO other_tbl (group, id) VALUES (value, 1);
INSERT INTO other_tbl (group, id) VALUES (value, 2);
INSERT INTO other_tbl (group, id) VALUES (value, 3);
INSERT INTO other_tbl (group, id) VALUES (value, 4);
```

This operation would be run as part of a database migration script, so it can't be done as a trigger after a different insert; the trigger actually already exists. I have looked around and the solution I found used cursors, but it was in MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten about using a queried value alongside an absolute value in the SELECT operation.

INSERT INTO other_tbl (group, id) SELECT value, 1 FROM ex_tbl WHERE (query);

INSERT INTO other_tbl (group, id) SELECT value, 2 FROM ex_tbl WHERE (query);

...